# Enable Keychain sharing for Swift Package Test Target

Tags: swift, xcode, keychain, swift-package-manager

I have created a Swift Package that will require Keychain sharing. Apps that use it can add the capability in Xcode.

However I have a test target in my package and want to be able to add Keychain sharing requirement when I run tests. Is this possible? I don't have an xcode project I only have a .package that I created, so don't know where to add this Keychain capability for the test target. XCTests will always fail now since the "app" that is running does not have this turned on.